# Windows Update Error 800B0001 in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Update fails with error code 800B0001 after installing fresh instance of Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Note: the system is connected to WSUS.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What update is failing to be installed.  Based on a Google search the problem is connected to WSUS I would wipe the system to resolve this problem.

Comment: Right you are, the system is connected to WSUS...

Comment: Updates can still be installed, but only from Windows Update ("Check online for updates from Windows Update"). The real issue is that updates are no longer automatic. Fine for security aware users, but not for normal users.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the WSUS server has [KB2720211](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2720211) installed.

Answer (score 3):

I get this error when updating at work, where there are both WSUS and proxy issues that block updates. However, clicking on the bottom link of your screen shot "Check online for updates from Windows Update" is more reliable and almost always gets thru.

Answer (score 0):

If you system is not connected to a WSUS server and have this problem.

Run the "System Update Readiness Tool" thsi also works for other system in the windows 7 family, for new system use DISM (Deployment Image Servicing and Management) Tool.

[Windows 7 32-bit versions x86-based](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=44e15787-66b0-4e9c-9c3b-1fc9ea40f69f)

[Windows 7 64-bit versions x64-based](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=914fbc5b-1fba-4bae-a7c3-d2c47c6fcffc)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness